# Creation of a windows service for RMI registry

Tags: java, windows, service, registry, rmi

I want to create a windows service for starting a RMI service on my system. The command I use to run this on cmd is

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\jre\bin\rmiregistry.exe 
>   -J-Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=false 11100

I have created a service using windows sc.exe using the command

> sc.exe create registry_service binPath= "C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\jre\bin\rmiregistry.exe 
>   -J-Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=false 11100"

But on starting this service I get a pop-up saying

> "Error1053: service did not respond to start or control request in
>   timely fashion."

Can anyone tell where i went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use any arbitrary .exe as a Windows service. There are special requirements. You need to use the Windows Service Wrapper, which you can download from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

In know that my response to this question is late, but perhaps it will help others who have the same question.

To install RMI as a windows service, you can make use of Apache’s Procrun (prunsrv). With Apache Procrun, you don't need to download anything from Microsoft. You don't need to download anything else either. I’ve used this many time for setting up Windows services and wrapping both Java and other exe programs as native windows services. Take a look at: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html

The following is a sample of how RmiRegistry.exe may be run as a windows native service using procrun.

1. To start the RMI Registry, we make use of the RmiRegistry.exe program.
2. To stop the RMI Registry, we make use of Windows TaskKill.exe program

In the command window give the following commands:

**To install RmiRegistry.exe as a native windows service**

```
set svcBaseDir="D:\nativeService"

%svcBaseDir%\bin\prunsrv64 //IS//RmiRegistrySvc ^
        --DisplayName="RMI Registry Service" ^
        --Install=%svcBaseDir%\bin\prunsrv64.exe ^
        --StartMode=exe ^
        --StopMode=exe ^
        --StartImage=<java install dir>\bin\rmiregistry.exe ^
        --StartParams=-J-Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=false#11100 ^
        --StopImage=C:\Windows\System32\taskkill.exe ^
        --StopParams=/F#/IM#rmiRegistry.exe ^
        --LogPath=%svcBaseDir%\logs ^
        --StdOutput=auto ^
        --StdError=auto ^
        --LogPrefix=Native-JNI- ^
        --LogLevel debug ^
        --ServiceUser <your windows domain>\<service user name> ^
        --ServicePassword <service password> ^
        --Description="Runs the RMI Registry as a Windows Service" ^
        --Startup=auto

set svcBaseDir=
```

Of course *D:\nativeService* is just an arbitrary directory name. You can choose any directory on any drive. I’m using the following directory structure for this native windows server, but you can use whatever you like:

```
D:\nativeService
|
---- bin
     |
     ---- prunsrv64.exe
----logs
```

Once  RmiRegistry.exe is installed as a native windows service, it can be started, stopped, and restarted   using window’s service manager, just like any other native windows service.

**To test or run the RmiRegistry.exe native windows service in the foreground (after it is installed)**

```
%svcBaseDir%\bin\prunsrv64 //TS//RmiRegistrySvc
```

**To Uninstall and remove the RmiRegistry.exe native windows service from Windows**

```
%svcBaseDir%\bin\prunsrv64 //DS//RmiRegistrySvc
```

Note that you use the 64-bit prunsrv only for 64 bit servers/computers, while the 32-bit prunsrv may be used for both 32 and 64 servers/computers.

I’ve renamed the downloaded prusrv.exe to prusrv64.exe for use on all 64-bit machines. This helps me differentiate between the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the prusrv.exe utility.